# API version 2022-03-01 does not have operation group 'virtual_machine_images'

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I run following command

```
az vm create --resource-group MyRG --name myVMName --image windows-11:win11–21h2-pro:22000.376.2112072052
```

This causes following error.

```
API version 2022-03-01 does not have operation group 'virtual_machine_images'
```

I assume this means --image no more support but what's the alternative? Couldn't find anything relevant in the Auzre cli documentation about this. My az cli version seems upto date

```
az --version                                                                                                                                        
azure-cli                         2.37.0
 
core                              2.37.0
telemetry                          1.0.6
 
Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.24.0
 
Dependencies:
msal                            1.18.0b1
azure-mgmt-resource               21.0.0
 
Python location '/usr/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/kali/.azure/cliextensions'
Extensions system directory '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure-cli-extensions'
 
Python (Linux) 3.10.5 (main, Jun  8 2022, 09:26:22) [GCC 11.3.0]
 
Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal
 
 
Your CLI is up-to-date.
```

**Update:**
This error is not specific to windows-11, I am getting same error with other OS too. See image below for detailed error.

[image]

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with Windows-11. I get same error when running az vm image list --all --offer CentOS too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> az vm create --resource-group MyRG --name myVMName --image
> windows-11:win11–21h2-pro:22000.376.2112072052

The image version you are using in your cmdlet is not supported. I would suggest you use the below Azure Cli cmdlet to see the list of supported `windows-11:win11-21h2-pro` images to deploy a virtual machine.

```
az vm image list --all --offer windows-11 --sku win11-21h2-pro -o table
```

**Below image shows when we ran the above cmdlet from Azure cloudshell:**

[image]

**Below image shows when we ran the above cmdlet from local AzureCLI:**

[image]

**Note:** I have tested the above `az vm image list` cmdlet in local & Azure Cloudshell  as well it is working fine,I am able to see the list of support images and their respective versions.

I have ran the below cmdlet, am able to deploy the virtual machine using the image (MicrosoftWindowsDesktop:windows-11:win11-21h2-pro:22000.675.220507).You just need to use the image version that is shown in the above list

```
az vm create --resource-group <resourcegroupName> --name <vmName> --image MicrosoftWindowsDesktop:windows-11:win11-21h2-pro:22000.675.220507
```

[image]

Comment: I get same error when running az vm image list --all --offer CentOS too

Comment: @whoami - I have the above cmdlet in the Azure Cloud Shell and i am able to see the list of Centos images as well here is the cmdlet used :  `az vm image list --all --offer Centos --publisher OpenLogic -o table`
Here is sample output for reference: https://i.imgur.com/otik3Ja.png

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why I am getting this error then.

Comment: @whoami - Are you running those cmdlets from the Azure cloud shell (in the portal) or from the Azure CLI in your local ?

Comment: Local. From Debian based linux machine.

Comment: @whoami - where able to connect to azure subscription using `az login cmdlet`? and also what is the error message you are getting while running the above `az vm image list` cmdlet

Comment: yes I can login. I updated question with screen shot of the OS version (where I am getting this issue) and also the full exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245944/discussion-between-venkateshdodda-msft-and-whoami).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I uninstalled azure-cli, re-installed using pip. I am no more getting this error. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/19369#issuecomment-906964374